# What are the effective ways of recording and maintaining test execution proofs?

Tags: manual-testing, agile-testing, regression-testing

We are following Agile Scrum in our project. While manual testing, we would like to maintain test execution proof which should be easy to capture and easy to maintain.

Currently, we are following the manual process of taking screenshots and using "Quick Time Player" for recording.

Can anyone suggest the better way of recording/capturing/maintaining of test execution proofs?

Comment: To suggest a better way we need to know what is the way you're currently using.

Comment: Are you using automated testing? If yes , you may configure it to take screenshots at critical verification points.

Comment: Since you have not mentioned what you are currently using, I'd suggest making use of automated Test Reports. Guess this will serve your purpose of maintaining Test Execution proof.

Comment: Currently, we are following the manual process of taking screenshots and using "Quick Time Player" for recording.

Answer (score 3):

Automate it, run it on a [build-server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software).

> I will produce, with each release, a quick, sure, and repeatable proof
>   that every element of the code works as it should.
>
> http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2015/11/18/TheProgrammersOath.html

If for some reason you do need todo it manual have a look at [**Session-based test management**](http://www.satisfice.com/sbtm/index.shtml). This seems to be Agile "compatible" and contains proof.

Still focus on automating most if not all of your test-cases. Preferable with lots of unit and integration tests.

Suggested resources:

- https://less.works/less/technical-excellence/index.html
- [Robert C. Martin - The Land that Scrum Forgot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hG4LH6P8Syk) (Video)